# use subprocess to make a windows CMD script work.

Tags: python, popen

I'd love to make this run. 
    import `subprocess`

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["@ECHO ON,", "SET TmpBatch=%temp%\~tmpLogonMessage.cmd,",
'IF EXIST "%TmpBatch%" DEL /Q /F "%TmpBatch%',  
"SET msgboxTitle=This is my Message Title,",
"SET msgboxLine1=This is my temp Message Window that pops up at Windows Logon,",
"SET tmpmsgbox=%temp%\~tmpmsgbox.vbs,",
'ECHO @ECHO OFF                                                    >>"%TmpBatch%",',
'ECHO IF EXIST "%tmpmsgbox%" DEL /F /Q "%tmpmsgbox%"               >>"%TmpBatch%",',
'ECHO ECHO msgbox "%msgboxLine1%",0,"%msgboxTitle%"^>"%tmpmsgbox%" >>"%TmpBatch%",',
'ECHO WSCRIPT "%tmpmsgbox%"                                        >>"%TmpBatch%",',
'START /MIN CMD /C "%TmpBatch%",', 'EXIT /B,'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: above directives looks good. Doesn't it work by itself?

Answer (score 0):

It is best to have all the script content in a bat file and then use **[subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)** to execute it:

EX:

```
import subprocess
filepath = "C:/path/to/bat/myBat.bat"
p = subprocess.Popen(filepath, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```